# Are water molecules orientation absolutely independent of the flow direction?

Tags: water, flow, molecules

Or is there a bias toward a specific angle in regards to the direction of the current?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

These types of questions are tempting to ask in a yes-no way, and you currently have an answer that says "yes" and and answer that says "no."
The physicist's approach is to ask *how big* the biggest effect might be; let's try that.

The current answer which proposes an aligning effect suggests an interaction between the electric dipole moment of the water molecule, $p \approx 6\times10^{-30}\,\mathrm{C\,m} \approx 0.4\,e\,Å$, and the Earths' magnetic field, via the Lorentz force, $\vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B$.  The energy associated with this interaction is what you get if the force interacts over the length scale of the molecule, which has a bond length of about $1\,Å$.  The typical thermal velocities obey $kT \approx mv^2$, or

\begin{align}
v^2 \sim \frac{kT}{m} = \frac{25\rm\,meV}{18\,\mathrm{GeV}/c^2}
&\approx \frac 43\times10^{-12}\ c^2
\\
v &\sim 10^{-6}\ c \approx 300 \rm\,m/s
\end{align}

So a typical Lorentz-force polarization energy would be

\begin{align}
U &\approx | p v B |
%\\ &= 6\times10^{-30} \mathrm{C\,m}\cdot 3\times10^2\mathrm{m/s} \cdot \frac12\times10^{-4}\mathrm T
%\\ &\approx 9\times10^{-32}\,\mathrm J
%\times\frac{1\rm\,eV}{1.6\times10^{-19}\rm\,J}
\\ &\approx \frac 58\times10^{-13} \rm\,eV
\approx 60 \rm\,feV
\end{align}

Those are femto-eV.
But the water molecule's rotational degree of freedom also has milli-eV energy sloshing around.  The ratio of the aligned and un-aligned populations will go like the Boltzmann factor for this energy difference,

$$
e^{\Delta E/kT} = e^{\text{femto/milli}} = 1 + 10^{-12},
$$

that is, a part-per-trillion difference.  I've been involved in several experiments looking for part-per-billion asymmetries; each one took ten years.  A few parts per trillion is a small effect, even if you go back through my arithmetic and futz around with some missing factors of two.

What's more, the preferred direction $\vec v \times \vec B$ is only well-defined if most of the water molecules are moving in generally the same direction.  That only happens if the rate of flow is much faster than the typical thermal velocity --- which doesn't really happen unless the flow approaches the speed of sound in water.

If you tried to enhance the effect --- by, say, shooting a hypersonic jet of water through the bore of ten-tesla magnet, to bring the asymmetry up to the part-per-million range --- you'd probably just learn something sneaky about hydrogen bonding.

Comment: It is initially a yes or no question so as to know if there is any effect at all in the first place, which I suspected there is without being sure. And then, but only after determining there is a correlation however small, quantative aspects matter. What does not appear in your answer even though it is the most interesting so far are other possible effects due to friction on the sides of the flow, changes of acceleration due to varying bed size along the stream, and self organizing domains of groups of water molecules for example.

Comment: I disagree with your philosophical approach: experience shows in physics that anything not forbidden is required. But we can compute whether an allowed behavior is common or rare.

Comment: Whatever. But ironically you do not address the rest of my comment.

Comment: My expertise is in subatomic physics. Friction is a mesoscale effect. Those length scales usually don't talk to each other. If you have a model in mind, I might have more time to think about it, but it seems like that could have been part of your original question.

Comment: @rob I think they might have been thinking about laminar flow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow

Comment: @nick012000 That was my first thought as well. The hydrogen bonds make the water molecules form chains in cold water (which consequently becomes "oily"). It's entirely conceivable that these line up with the flow in laminar flowing conditions, and potentially even interact.

Comment: Well, suppose that such "chains" exist (hydrogen bonding is pretty sneaky) and that there's a net correlation between the total dipole moment $\vec p$ of such a chain and the flow velocity $\vec v$. For a net transverse correlation $\vec p\times\vec v$, there has to be some external interaction that breaks the symmetry, and we're back to thinking about something like a magnetic field, as in the answer. If there's a front-back correlation $\vec p\cdot\vec v$, that means water flow breaks charge conjugation symmetry. Which isn't impossible, but is unlikely, and doesn't fit in a comment.

Comment: "shooting a hypersonic jet of water through the bore of ten-tesla magnet, to bring the asymmetry up to the part-per-million range " - I'd love to hear about that experiment actually having been done and what the results were.

Comment: @JohnDvorak:  [starts writing grant proposal]

Comment: @nick012000: feel free to elaborate and post an answer. I am still unsatisfied by the current answers in terms of comprehensiveness.

Comment: @Peter - Reinstate Monica: feel free to elaborate and post an answer. I am still unsatisfied by the current answers in terms of comprehensiveness.

Comment: @Exocytosis I'm a computer programmer, not a physicist, so I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: @rob I think the "chains" would be aligned by sheer, so a more macroscopic/mechanical interaction. Googling seems to indicate that such phenomena exist in true polymers (which is of course less surprising). On the other hand, my offhand claim about "chain formation" in cold water seems less founded; the molecules appear to build tetrahedrons rather. Seeing no solid argument forming I abandoned the idea of writing an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a bias. Water molecules jiggle around so much in the liquid that any long-range order (like dipoles getting all lined up) has no chance to form, and if it did form for any reason, it would be very quickly erased.

Comment: I read papers that describe long range interactions in water when it is steady, forming domains. I concur that this probably does not apply to an accelerating flow of water. Even if the effect is extremely small and whatever the reason behind it, I am interested though.

Comment: @Exocytosis Regarding "I read papers": links to such papers would be helpful.

Comment: @rob: I am not the one tring to answer here. If you are not aware of this research maybe you are just not the one that should attempt to answer. Your answer cares about very few physical phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

Because water molecule has a dipole moment, in the earth magnetic field it is subjected to the Lorentz force.

Comment: True only in principle. First, it's a nano-eV effect for water molecules with thermal velocities, while the rotational degree of freedom has milli-eV mean energy. Second, the energy preference only corresponds to a preferred direction if the flow rate is comparable to the thermal velocities, which are hundreds of meters per second.

Comment: @rob. it depends on the flow speed

Comment: I do not know why you got downvoted, I am upvoting this so as to balance.

Comment: This answer assumes the experience is done on Earth in a region where the magnetic field is not shielded. But the question never specified that these conditions had to be met. So this answer is, at best, incomplete.

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson: In fact I specified in the earth magnetic field. It's difficult to imagine a water flow in the empty space.

Comment: It's not empty space but also not terrestrial: there is plumbing aboard the ISS.

Comment: Would this only apply when a flow has an east/west component? Also, my understanding is that the word "flow" refers to motion relative to the container, but this is motion relative to the Earth. This would apply equally well to water in a moving vehicle as water flowing through a pipe.

Comment: @Edward, the ISS is still within the earth’s magnetic field. I think the intensity is about 2/3 of that at the surface.

Comment: @prl Mention of the ISS was mostly intended to address the phrase “it’s hard to imagine...” Also note that Earth’s magnetic field isn’t uniform; the ISS regularly traverses the South Atlantic Anomaly, for example. See https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-researchers-track-slowly-splitting-dent-in-earth-s-magnetic-field

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson the Earth's magnetic field extends through the vast majority of the observable universe.

Comment: @PyRulez But attenuated to beyond what is measurable not too far from Earth, right? And a shield of mu metal can be made to block it too, right? So... not hard to imagine to me.